# Java difference between (classpath relative path) and (document relative path)?

Tags: java, javafx, classpath

> Description

I am trying to understand what the above means.I have a project with the below schema:

[image]

> ~~->And here is an image from the [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/):

[image]

> The problem

First i want to access the `image1.png` using (**document relative path**) which i think it is `../../resources/images/image1.png` and then i want to access `image2.png` using (**classpath relative path**) which i have no idea what it means.

> Finally

1. I want to be soore that when i export the application as a `.jar`
   file the images which are inside the `.jar` files are shown as they
   are shown when i open the application in Eclipse.
2. This is actually about `Java 9`.I have to change anything so the
   project is running smoothly with `Java 9`?Will even `.jar` files be
   accepted?I am curious for that.

Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Classpath relative** means the path will be relative to the classpath of the classloader used for loading the fxml file. You most likely do not want to use this option. Instead the document relative path: since `src` is not exported in to the jar, in `Main.fxml` this should be

```
@../images/image1.png
```

or

```
@../resources/images/image1.png
```

depending on eclipse storing the resources in a `resources` directory in the jar file or not. (Note SceneBuilder automatically adds the `@`, if you select the appropriate option.)

As java 9 is concerned, I cannot tell you for sure, but the documentation contains a constant for the `@` prefix so it's unlikely that document relative paths are removed in java 9.

Comment: Hm so Classpath relative in this case means that the path will be relative to the class that is loading the fxml file ?